# Referencing a class through another jar using reflection

Tags: java, reflection

I am doing a project involving a standalone jar. let's call it JAR "A".  Jar "B" and JAR "C" are accessible to JAR "A", like this:

```
+JAR "A"
      + lib 
         + JAR "C"
         + JAR "B"
```

JAR "A" has inside it's `MANIFEST.MF` the classpath pointing to "B" and "C" inside `lib/` correctly. It indeed can find classes from both jars with this code:

```java
 Class<?> clazz22 = Class.forName("sampleClassFromC");
 System.out.println(" :: declared fields: " + clazz22.getDeclaredFields().length);
```

The problem is that, I need to load all classes from "C" and list its class names and attributes. And some classes from "C" reference classes from "B". When a class from "C" has some imports from "B", then java throws an exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException.
```

What do I need to do so that, when I read by reflection "C" classes which have "B" imports, it won't throw exceptions? Thanks.